# "Да сам большой"

Tags: литература, лексика, стилистика

Мой идеал теперь - хозяйка.
Мои желания - покой,
Да щей горшок, да сам большой.

*(А.С.Пушкин. "Евгений Онегин")*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает **"да сам большой"**?

Comment: Может быть, это такое авторское сокращение от *самый большой*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*ЩЕЙ ГОРШОК ДА САМ БОЛЬШОЙ. Устар. Сам себе хозяин. Говорится о том, кто живет в достатке и ни от кого не зависит.*
Словарь пословиц.
Добавлю.
Видимо от "большой" - старший в доме, иногда еще и сейчас употребляется наряду с "меньшой" и "малой".

Есть, правда, еще и версия, что сам - урожай. Вернее отношение собранного к посеянному. Считали так: сам-друг - собрали в два раза больше чем посеяли. Сам-пят, сам-шост, сам-сём - в пять, шесть, семь раз больше. и т.д. (Насчет 3 и 4 не уверен, кажется сам-трем и сам-четыр).

//==============

Оказывается, слово "сам" есть у Ушакова:

САМ- (обл.). Первая часть неизм. прил., сложных с числ. порядковыми: ***друг, третей, четвёрт, пят, шост, сём, осьмой, девят, десят*** или количественными, со значениями: 1) во столько-то раз больше посеянного (сколько указывает числ.). Сам-друг (вдвое). Пшеница уродилась только сам-друг. Урожай сам-шост (в шесть раз больше посеянного), сам-восемь, сам-двадцать и т.д. 2) столько-то (сколько указывает числ.), считая вместе с самим действующим лицом, субъектом речи. Сам-друг (вдвоем). Он сам-шост (т.е. семья его состоит из шести лиц, считая его самого). «Я сам-друг с тобой, слуга и хозяин.» А.Кольцов. «Осталася во тьме морозной младая дева с ним сам-друг.» Пушкин. «Остался Семен с женою сам-друг.» Гаршин.

Курсив мой. Что-то оплошал я насчет 3 и 4. А ведь знал же)))
Но, повторюсь, не поручусь, что именно это значение вошло в пословицу. Хотя когда-то активно эту версию "разрабатывал".

*А вообще долго обсуждалось на Грамоте. Опять не могу найти, потерли он архивы, что ли.*

Comment: >Считали так: сам-друг - собрали в два раза больше чем посеяли. Сам-пят, сам-шост, сам-сём - в пять, шесть, семь раз больше. и т.д. 

Это очень интересно, спасибо. 
<br><br>
Мне интересны старые русские обороты речи.

Comment: >Считали так: сам-друг - собрали в два раза больше чем посеяли. Сам-пят, сам-шост, сам-сём - в пять, шесть, семь раз больше. и т.д. 

В данном случае мне показалось любопытным, что эти слова очень похожи на *украинские* (а не на современные *русские*) числительные. Сравните. Напишу, для простоты прочтения, по русским правилам, а в скобках -- украинское правописание.

ДрУгый (другий), шОстый (шостий), сЁмый (сьомий). 

Интересно было узнать, что в русском языке слово "второй", точнее связанное с ним по смыслу слово "сам-друг" может происходить от корня "друг"

Comment: В словаре языка Пушкина так и сказано: независимый, самостоятельный. Хороший вопрос, интересный ответ.

Comment: Да, я знаю, смотрел еще в грамотовские времена. Но случалось и со словарем поспорить...

Answer (score 0):

> VI, 201 — Да щей горшок, да сам большой. — Цитата из пятой сатиры
> Кантемира «На человеческое злонравие вообще.   Щей горшок, да сам
> большой, хозяин я дома...
>
> (Кантемир А. Собр. стихотворений. Л., 1956. С. 137)

Источник: http://pushkin-lit.ru/pushkin/articles/lotman/onegin-kommentarij/onegin-comments-9.htm

Comment: Это возможный источник (сомнительный, кстати, как первоисточник). А вопрос-то был о значении.